# PHP constructor uses?

Tags: php, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Benefits of using a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403756/benefits-of-using-a-constructor)

I am learning some PHP OOP and I have a question about constructors.

Why would you use a constructor and not just call a method instead?

I understand that constructors are called the moment a new object is created. But why the need for a special __construct function? What is so special about them?