# purpose of constructor in php

Tags: php, oop, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Benefits of using a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403756/benefits-of-using-a-constructor)

hello coders. I am newbie to OOP in php.  I am doing a project in objects and class. where
most of time I face a line

```
public function __construct(){
}
```

I can't understand this. Why its used and what is its value. Can some one tell me about it. I went to  the php.net site but my doubt not cleared.

Comment: The purpose of a constructor is not limited to PHP but to all OO programming languages.

Comment: It is useful only if it actually contains code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The __construct allows arguments to be passed to an object on initalisation, without you would do something like this:

```
$myobj = new Object();
$myobj->setName('Barry');
```

But if you have this:

```
public function __construct($name='')
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

You can just do:

```
$myobj = new Object('Barry');
```

Another possible use for the constructor (though not good practice):

```
public function __construct()
{
    ob_start(); //Some random code that you may want to run as soon as object is initialised
}
```

Comment: About your last part: Ctors should not do work. They should not run code. The purpose of a ctor is to set an object into a valid state. Nothing more.

Comment: Yes, but there is a difference between "should not" and "cannot". The OP asked why they are used, the last example is how it could possibly be used, I never said it was a good thing to do - I just answered the question.

Comment: That's a pretty odd explanation, don't you think? I mean, sure, you *can* do that in a ctor. You *can* also put your entire logic into it. But that isn't why we use ctors, nor what we use them for. Showing the OP how it *can* be used when it shouldnt be used like that, is not really helpful. Your first examples are fine. The last one isnt.

Comment: Ok, you aren't understanding what I'm saying. I'll put that down to a problem with your screen - either way, I'm not going to be continuing this argument.

Comment: Well, at least you put that it's not good practise.

Answer (score 8):

when using oop, a constructor gives basic initialization details for an object.

See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)#PHP

Answer (score 0):

It's a method within a class. When you construct an object from a class, this associated constructor is called. It has the "__" magic method prefix.

Answer (score 0):

This method is automatically called when a class is instantiated.

There is also a `__destruct()` method, which as you might guess is automatically called when a class is destroyed.

Have a read here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `__construct` is to initialize any newly created object in a method that's native to OO design.

So, rather than doing something like this:

```
$o = new MyObject();
$o->Initialize();
```

We can simply do this:

```
$o = new MyObject();
```

And within the MyObject class:

```
class MyObject
{
    public function __contruct()
    {
        // initialization code here
    }
}
```